# How can I write a redirection code using C in Lunux?

Tags: c, pipe, io-redirection

My homework is to make this sentence of command work in Linux using C

"cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1 > userlist.txt"

I had to used only dup2(), execl(), mkfifo, pipe() function to finish this homework.

I could accomplish

"cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1"

successfully.

```
pid_t pid;
int pipefd[2] = {0, };

if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
perror("pipe() error!");
return -1;
}

pid = fork();

if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork() error!");
}
else if (pid == 0) { // Child
close(pipefd[0]);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL);
}
else { // Parent
close(pipefd[1]); // close unused write end
wait(&pid);
dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
execl("/usr/bin/cut", "cut", "-d", ":", "-f", "1", NULL);
}
```

Comment: Think a little bit about what [the `wait` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) does, and what might have happened to the pipe once the child process have exited. Consider using a second child for the second command, or simply not `wait` at all (child process would then be reaped by the system).

Comment: And just to nitpick, the program you make isn't really *redirection* in the shell sense, it's just plain piping, as in `cat ... | cut ...` in a shell.